# URL::openStream throws "SocketException: Socket closed" unconditionally

Tags: java, networking

I'm running on a MacBook Pro with macOS Catalina.

Using Java's `java.net.URL` class, I should be able to read data from a URL. However, no matter what I do, I get `java.net.SocketException: Socket closed`.

This program is a minimal example of the problem:

```java
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://example.com/");
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
    }
}
```

When executing it, the `SocketException` occurs and `java` exits with an error:

```
$ javac Example.java && java Example
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:746)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:717)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1604)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1117)
    at Example.main(Example.java:7)
$ echo $?
1
```

The expected result would be no output and a zero exit code.

The above example was run with this Java version (but the same error happens with other Java versions):

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.29+3-CA (build 11.0.2+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.29+3-CA (build 11.0.2+7-LTS, mixed mode)
```

This happens with every Java version I've tried (e.g. OpenJDK 15 or Zulu 11). It does not matter what website I use, nor does it matter if a hostname or IP address is used, nor does it matter if it's HTTP or HTTPS, nor does it matter what port (80, 443, non-standard). It happens when talking to services on the local machine and ones on the internet. The issue persists after restarts.

Comment: Could you post a call stack with a non ssh url used, to get rid of all this ssh stuff which really obfuscates things? And the java version/edition used in this precise call, pls.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your program on my machine (JDK 11) and works like a charm.

I suppose the problem is not java but rather where you execute the code.
Is it a virtual machine or Container (Docker) ?
This could also be firewall related.
My money is on a network configuration problem of some sort.

Comment: I'm running on a MacBook Pro with macOS Catalina. To test this out more, I've tried with Python (working): `python3 -c 'import requests; print(requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/"));'`. I think you're absolutely on the right track with it being a network config issue, perhaps something specific to the JVM?